# Call a child function in different file from parent in react?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have a class Parent class I want to call a child function from it. (when a button is clicked) , the button is in parent class.how to achieve this..
**Both classes are in different files**

below is my code

```
import React from "react";
var Parent = React.createClass({

 render: function() {

     return (
         <div>
            <button onClick={() => callchildfunction()}>Click</button> 
         </div>
      );
 }
})



// both classes are in different files


import React from "react";
var child = React.createClass({

    callchildfunction: function(){

        console.log("child function is called from parent")
    }

})
```

Comment: where is `child` used in `Parent`?

Comment: If you just want to call some function from another file, then you can `create a file`, `add the function in that file`, `export that function` and then `import that function/file` in your Parent class.

Answer (score 0):

When your Child component exists in parent render method, you can use refs from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html,